# Validar form sin que borren los datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

Buenas tengo un formulario simple, deseo validar los campos no estén vacíos y que la ID no este duplicada, pero a la vez que no se borren aquellos campos que estén bien ingresados. Tengo el siguiente código.

```js
<script>
            $(document).on("ready", function(){
            mostrar_mensaje();
        });
        var mostrar_mensaje = function() {
            $(".mensaje").fadeOut(4000, function() {
                $(this).html("");
                $(this).fadeIn(4000);
            });
        }
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" name="submit" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3 class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 text-center">                   
                    Formulario  </h3>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="deceto" class="col-sm-2 control-label">N° Decreto</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input id="decreto" name="decreto" type="text" class="form-control" autofocus>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fecha" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input id="fecha" name="fecha" type="date" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="materia" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Materia</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="materia" id="materia" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar" />
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php
            include 'conexion.php'
            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $decreto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['decreto']);
    $fecha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['fecha']);
    $materia = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['materia']);
    $anno=date("Y");
    $decreto_id =$anno.$decreto;
    if (!empty($decreto) || !empty($fecha) || !empty($materia))
        {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM decreto WHERE decreto_id='$decreto_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck > 0)
            { ?>    <div class="mensaje" id="mensaje">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <strong>Error</strong> N° decreto ya existe
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
  else
    {
    $sqll = "INSERT INTO decreto (decreto_id,anno,materia,decreto,fecha) VALUES ('$decreto_id','$fecha','$materia','$decreto','$anno')";
    $resultt = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqll);
    if ($resultt)
        $query ="INSERT INTO decreto_anno (decreto_id,anno) VALUES ('$decreto_id','$anno')";
     $resulttt = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
        { ?>
    <div class="mensaje" id="mensaje">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <strong>Bien! decreto ingresado exitosamente</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } } } else { ?>
    <div class="mensaje" id="mensaje">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <strong>Error campos vacios</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } } ?>
```

Al momento de apretar el btn guardar me valida bien pero los  campos después quedan en blancos. He leído que con Ajax se puede hacer un poco mas dinámico el form  intentare aplicarle un  poco de Ajax al form. Espero que sea claro saludos esta atento al post.

Comment: JS es lo que te ayudará a darle dinamismo a la validación de tu formulario. Tomas cada valor de cada campo, revisas si pasa la validación, de lo contrario borras o reseteas el campo y pasas al siguiente y así sucesivamente, sin usar nada de ajax. Ajax es para llamadas asíncronas al servidor no para validaciones del lado del cliente.

Comment: Pero y si deseo validar que la ID no se repita no debo estar de lado del servidor cierto?

Answer (score -1):

Intenta validar los campos desde el cliente con JavaScript, sería algo como:

Primero, agrega un `id` al form

```
<form id="myForm" ....>
```

Accede al form desde JavaScript y detén la acción por defecto (que es enviar el form al servidor y cambiar la ruta hacia "#")

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // valida la forma, aquí puedes hacer los envíos por AJAX
  // ejemplo para saber si el id del decreto es válido, envía el valor
  // del decreto y revísalo por php, así se enviaría con JS

  var decretoId = $('#decreto').val();

  $.ajax({ url: '#?decreto=', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json' })
  .success(function(data) {
    // suponiendo que php ha devuelto un json que dice { "valid": false }
    if(!data.valid) {
      decreto.val('');
    }
  });
});
```

Espero te sirva :)

Comment: ¿Para que usar ajax sin con simples comparaciones desde javascript es suficiente?

Comment: ¿Cómo validas que no sea un `id` duplicado? Si esa información la conoce es el servidor, creo que lo más sano es preguntarle.

Comment: Si desde la forma puedes ingresar ids duplicados entonces lo que esta mal es el diseño de la misma, ese tipo de validaciones no deberían de hacerse, si el id no existe es un insert, si el id está duplicado es un update/delete.